# How is concatenate being used in this context?

Tags: r

I was trying out the paste function,when things got a bit interesting.I want to understand why concatenate c() is functioning very differently here.

I have implemented 2 different scenarios as you can see.

1)

```
paste("X","Y",1:10)
```

2)

```
paste1<-paste(c("X","Y"),1:10,sep="")
```

1)Output from case 1:-

```
"X Y 1"  "X Y 2"  "X Y 3"  "X Y 4"  "X Y 5"  "X Y 6"  "X Y 7"  "X Y 8"  "X Y 9"  "X Y 10"
```

2)Output from case 2:-

```
"X1"  "Y2"  "X3"  "Y4"  "X5"  "Y6"  "X7"  "Y8"  "X9"  "Y10"
```

Comment: It is the *recycling rule*. 1) is equivalent to `paste(rep("X",10),rep("Y", 10),1:10)` but 2) is equivalent to `paste(rep(c("X","Y"), 5),1:10,sep="")`

Comment: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/vector-arithmetics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are pasting together `X`, `Y` and a sequence `1:10`. Thus, `X` and `Y` is always present and only the number at the end changes.

In the second case, you are recycling the `c("X","Y")` vector until the length of sequence `1:10`. It means, that it takes `X`, pastes it together with `1`, takes `Y`, pastes it together with `2`, takes `X` again, pastes it together with `3` and so on (until reaching `10`).

The exact wording of the [recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html):

> If one tries to add two structures with a different number of
>   elements, then the shortest is recycled to length of longest. That is,
>   if for instance you add c(1, 2, 3) to a six-element vector then you
>   will really add c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3).

Comment: Thanks tmfmnk,it is due to the numbers that recycling rule is getting applied. jogo please explain the second part of your explanation.The code works  but how is working?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: Thanks tmfmnk and jogo.The link you gave really helped.